# how to set max length of mobile no and zip code using fluent api?

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s=>s.firstName).HasMaxLength(6).IsFixedLength().IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.zip).HasMaxLength(4).IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.firstName).IsRequired();

    //modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.lastName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(8);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.mobileNumber).HasMaxLength(10).IsFixedLength();
}
```

I'm trying to add fixed length validation on mobile number and zip core but it does not work.
It is working fine for first name and last name but not for integer type and long type.
Is there any way to validate these fields.

```
//student class

public class Student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public long mobileNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string streetName { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public int zip { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully those aren't real max lengths for names :)

Comment: I would advice you not to store phone numbers as integer or long. A numeric type shoul in my opinion be used if you (maybe later) want to perform calculations on that number, a phone number should be stored as string...

Comment: @misanthrop The same goes for zip code, especially if you consider that some countries (the UK, for example) use non-numeric postal codes. Of course, it depends on the scope of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Numeric values can be configured via `HasPrecision` method.

```
    Property(e => e.zip)
        .HasPrecision(4, 0);
```

`4` is the value bevor the colon, `0` everything after the colon.

But you may want to change 'zip' to string. Some zip-codes include characters or have leading zeros.

Comment: Maybe not supported by your database provider. Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL server